# Как работать на Android эмуляторе через HTTP прокси?

Tags: android, proxy, прокси, эмулятор

Использование параметра командной строки `-http-proxy` или переменной `http_proxy` не помогает на Android 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы через обозреватель выйти в сеть (например, на google.ru) изменить прокси там

```
Wireless & networks settings > Mobile networks > Access Point Names > TelKila > Proxy | Port
```